# How to fix an encoding migrating Python subprocess to unicode_literals?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-unicode

We're preparing to move to Python 3.4 and added unicode_literals. Our code relies extensively on piping to/from external utilities using subprocess module. The following code snippet works fine on Python 2.7 to pipe UTF-8 strings to a sub-process:

```
kw = {}
kw[u'stdin'] = subprocess.PIPE
kw[u'stdout'] = subprocess.PIPE
kw[u'stderr'] = subprocess.PIPE
kw[u'executable'] = u'/path/to/binary/utility'
args = [u'', u'-l', u'nl']

line = u'¡Basta Ya!'

popen = subprocess.Popen(args,**kw)
popen.stdin.write('%s\n' % line.encode(u'utf-8'))
...blah blah...
```

The following changes throw this error:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

kw = {}
kw[u'stdin'] = subprocess.PIPE
kw[u'stdout'] = subprocess.PIPE
kw[u'stderr'] = subprocess.PIPE
kw[u'executable'] = u'/path/to/binary/utility'
args = [u'', u'-l', u'nl']

line = u'¡Basta Ya!'

popen = subprocess.Popen(args,**kw)
popen.stdin.write('%s\n' % line.encode(u'utf-8'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 138, in <module>
    exitcode = main()
  File "test.py", line 57, in main
    popen.stdin.write('%s\n' % line.encode('utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any suggestions to pass UTF-8 through the pipe?

Comment: thanks for this, I had the exact same situation & problem and this thread was a huge help. I also found that in some simple cases, `sh.py` (available here: https://github.com/amoffat/sh ) has been an easy, portable, and compatible drop-in replacement for some of the `subprocess` craziness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'%s\n'` is a unicode string when you use `unicode_literals`:

```
>>> line = u'¡Basta Ya!'
>>> '%s\n' % line.encode(u'utf-8')
'\xc2\xa1Basta Ya!\n'
>>> u'%s\n' % line.encode(u'utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What happens is that your encoded `line` value is being *decoded* to interpolate into the unicode `'%s\n'` string.

You'll have to use a *byte string* instead; prefix the string with `b`:

```
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> line = u'¡Basta Ya!'
>>> b'%s\n' % line.encode(u'utf-8')
'\xc2\xa1Basta Ya!\n'
```

or encode *after* interpolation:

```
>>> line = u'¡Basta Ya!'
>>> ('%s\n' % line).encode(u'utf-8')
'\xc2\xa1Basta Ya!\n'
```

In Python 3, you'll have to write bytestrings to pipes anyway.

Comment: I removed the `TextIOWrapper()` option again as it won't work in Python 2; the pipe objects are not based on the `io` abstract base classes and wrapping fails.

Comment: Excellent! It works. It also created a warning in another place. I'll address that in another question. Thanks!

Comment: if `universal_newlines=True` then you could write text on Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

If `utf-8` stands for your locale encoding then to communicate using Unicode strings, you could use `universal_newlines=True` on Python 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['/path/to/binary/utility', '-l', 'nl'],
          stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,
          universal_newlines=True)
out, err = p.communicate('¡Basta Ya!')
```

The code works even if the locale's encoding is not utf-8. Input/output are Unicode strings here (`str` type).

If the subprocess requires `utf-8` whatever the current locale is then communicate using bytestrings instead (pass/read bytes):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['/path/to/binary/utility', '-l', 'nl'],
          stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = map(lambda b: b.decode('utf-8').replace(os.linesep, '\n'),
               p.communicate((u'¡Basta Ya!' + os.linesep).encode('utf-8')))
```

The code works the same on both Python 2 and 3.