# Is there a better way to retrieve strings from Python subprocess pipes with unicode_literals?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-unicode

Another question looked at how to pipe byte strings to subprocess.Popen's to stdin when using unicode_literals. [How to fix an encoding migrating Python subprocess to unicode_literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722720/how-to-fix-an-encoding-migrating-python-subprocess-to-unicode-literals/). The answer there fixed the problem and created a warning when collecting the subprocess' stdout strings.

Still using:

```
from future import unicode_literals
```

Initially, I got the same UnicodeDecodeError error when collecting stdout. So! Using my new knowledge, I updated the receiving code that services stdout in a separate thread:

```
for text in iter(popen.stdout.readline,''):
    text = text.decode(encoding)
    text = text.strip(' \r\n')
```

This fixed the error, but a new warning appeared:

```
test.py:456: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  for text in iter(popen.stdout.readline,''):
```

With a little searching, I found I can suppress the warning message like this:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    for text in iter(popen.stdout.readline,''):
        text = text.decode('utf-8')
        text = text.strip(' \r\n')
```

QUESTION: Is there a way to resolve the mismatch or is suppressing the the best way to handle this?

Comment: `popen.stdout.readline` returns a byte-string, not a Unicode string; but you're comparing it with the Unicode string `''` -- that's clearly your bug.  Use `b''` instead and it should work better (w/o suppressing useful warnings!-).

Comment: Thanks, Alex. If you convert your comment into an answer, I can accept it and close this question... Happy New Year everyone!

Comment: done, the answer's in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`popen.stdout.readline` returns a byte-string, not a Unicode string; but you're comparing it with the Unicode string `''`. Use b'' instead and it should work better (w/o suppressing useful warnings!-):

```
for text in iter(popen.stdout.readline, b''):
```